# Switch expression doesn't actually seem to be an expression in Dart 3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, language-lawyer

In Dart 3.0, *switch expression* is finally introduced today.

According to [the official documentation](https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-expressions),

> *A switch expression is similar to a switch statement, but you can use them anywhere you can use an expression.*

However, the code below doesn't compile ([DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8c453aeeae382707e9ecbfc26e55da5c)):

```dart
enum Color { red, blue, green }

void main() {
  final color = Color.red;
  switch (color) {
    Color.red => "red",
    Color.blue => "blue",
    Color.green => "green",
  };
}
```

though these code compile:

```dart
enum Color { red, blue, green }

void main() {
  final color = Color.red;
  //binds to placeholder
  final _ = switch (color) {
    Color.red => "red",
    Color.blue => "blue",
    Color.green => "green",
  };
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  3; //expression statement
}
```

Why?

(This question is about the language itself rather than practical applications. So the codes above are minimal but aren't useful. Thus I added `#language-lawyer` tag.)

Note, in Rust, the equivalent code compiles:

```rust
enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}

fn main() {
    let color = Color::Red;
    match (color) {
        Color::Red => "red",
        Color::Blue => "blue",
        Color::Green => "green",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch expression at a start of an expression statement is explicitly forbidden by [the language spec](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/future-releases/0546-patterns/feature-specification.md#expression-statement-ambiguity). Here's the relevant snippet from the spec:

---

##### Expression statement ambiguity

Thanks to expression statements, a switch expression could appear in the same
position as a switch statement. This isn't technically ambiguous, but requires
unbounded lookahead to read past the value expression to the first `case` in
order to tell if a switch in statement position is a statement or expression.

```dart
main() {
  switch (some(extremely, long, expression, here)) {
    _ => expression()
  };

  switch (some(extremely, long, expression, here)) {
    case _: statement();
  }
}
```

To avoid that, we disallow a switch expression from appearing at the beginning
of an expression statement. This is similar to existing restrictions on map
literals appearing in expression statements. In the rare case where a user
really wants one there, they can parenthesize it.

---

So the fix would be parenthesizing the expression:

```dart
enum Color { red, blue, green }

void main() {
  final color = Color.red;
  (switch (color) {
    Color.red => "red",
    Color.blue => "blue",
    Color.green => "green",
  });
}
```

ref: [dart-lang/language #3061](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/3061).